# Meaning of $p(y|f)$ in Gaussian Processes

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-process

I'm now starting with Gaussian Processes and I have a doubt related to it. I find this topic quite difficult to me to get started.

I have a $f\sim\mathcal{GP}(0,K)$. Now I have the data $x$ and $p(f|x)$ follows a Normal distribution with mean 0 and covariance $K$ over the points of $x$. 
Now I have noisy data $y=f(x)+\epsilon$, $\epsilon\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\beta^{-1}I)$.

What is the meaning of $p(y|f)$ and why is $p(y|f)=\mathcal{N}(y|f,\beta^{-1}I)$?

And what about $p(y|x)=\mathcal{N}(y|0,K+\beta^{-1} I)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p(y|f)$ means the probability pf $y$ given $f$. We're assuming that your observations $y$ are the result of the underlying function $f$ plus a normally distributed noise term: $y = f(x) + \epsilon$, $\epsilon \sim N(0, \beta^{-1}I)$. This is equivalent to $p(y|f) = N(f, \beta^{-1}I)$.

Next, we want to know the distribution of $y$ given $x$ instead of $y$ given $f$. We know how $y$ depends on $f$, and we know how $f$ depends on $x$, so we can derive the dependence of $y$ on $x$.

Comment: But why $p(y|f)$ follows that distribution ? I don't see how to compute it. And what do you mean by "derive" dependence?

Comment: $y$ is the underlying function $f$ plus the noise. The noise is normally-distributed with zero-mean and has some variance $\beta$. So the mean for each $y(x)$ is the corresponding function value $f(x)$, and it's variance is still $\beta$.